# Connection Timeout not working for Azure Storage Queue Client

Tags: c#, azure-storage-queues

I wonder why I cannot set a timeout. If I cannot submit a message to a queue within a few seconds I rather cancel the attempt and do an exponential back off.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet

```
QueueRequestOptions queueRequestOptions = new QueueRequestOptions();
queueRequestOptions.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext();
OperationContext.DefaultLogLevel = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.LogLevel.Verbose;
operationContext.ClientRequestID = correlationId;
operationContext.CustomUserAgent = "myCallerId";

await queue.AddMessageAsync(message, null, null, queueRequestOptions, operationContext);
```

Not exactly pretty but neither fulfilling its job :(
If I set a wrong dns name for the storage account, the request does not time out after 3 seconds as expected.

Given the fact that there is a HttpClient behind the scenes it should be possible to set a timeout for http calls.

```
CloudQueueClient cloudQueueClient = _cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
cloudQueueClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```

That was not working either.

In the meantime I had a look at the source code of the Azure Storage SDK:

```
namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol
{
    internal static class HttpClientFactory
    {
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Serializable]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly HttpClientFactory.<>c <>9 = new HttpClientFactory.<>c();

        internal HttpClient cctor>b__3_0()
        {
            HttpClient expr_0B = new HttpClient(StorageAuthenticationHttpHandler.Instance, false);
            expr_0B.get_DefaultRequestHeaders().set_ExpectContinue(new bool?(false));
            expr_0B.get_DefaultRequestHeaders().get_UserAgent().Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Azure-Storage", "8.5.0"));
            expr_0B.get_DefaultRequestHeaders().get_UserAgent().Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue(Constants.HeaderConstants.UserAgentComment));
            expr_0B.get_DefaultRequestHeaders().TryAddWithoutValidation("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");
            expr_0B.set_Timeout(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            return expr_0B;
        }
    }

    private static Lazy<HttpClient> instance = new Lazy<HttpClient>(new Func<HttpClient>(HttpClientFactory.<>c.<>9.<.cctor>b__3_0));

    public static HttpClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpClientFactory.instance.get_Value();
        }
    }
}
}
```

So the timeout is being set. To Infinite. And I couldn't find any place where the Timeout is being set to a different value. Can it be true? -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting queueRequestOptions.MaximumExecutionTime. That is the client-side timeout. The server timeout is passed to the service and is not enforced on the client.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-storage-retry-guidelines for more details.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out there is a built-in retry policy which "prevents" us from setting a simple timeout value.